# Adjust color scale of image plot in R

Tags: r, image, colorbar

The `image.plot` function automatically generate the color scale for the inputs. For example,

```
library(fields)
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:15
z <- outer(x, y, "+")
image.plot(x, y, z)
```

will generate a figure like this
[image]
Now I want to adjust the color scale to the range from 0 to 20, and any values above 20 need to be colored the same as 20. So I added `zlim=c(0,20)` in the function parameters, and I get,
[image]
The problem is, although `zlim` adjusted the color scale range, the values above the limit were not assigned a color. How can I fix this? In this case, I want the up-right corner to be colored dark red i.e. to have the color assigned from the end of the color range.

Comment: Seems like some kind of adjusted color scale is needed. There would be a linear part in range [0,20] and a flat part in range [20,30].

Comment: Hard-core code needed? In some functions (e.g. spplot), in fact, the range can be set to be [20, Inf], which is quite useful.@Heikki

Comment: A kind of hard-core, but it is very common to adjust color scales in for example Excel. Indeed, maybe some other function may be more useful. If you happen to find an answer yourself, don't hesitate to answer yourself to your own question and mark the answer correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `z[z > 20] <- 20` to achieve that with `image.plot`.

```
library(fields)
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:15
z <- outer(x, y, "+")
z[z > 20] <- 20
image.plot(x, y, z)
```

[image]

Comment: Smart way to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to get one solution by using levelplot function from lattice package.

```
grid=expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
grid$z=as.vector(z)
levelplot(z~x*y,grid,at=c(seq(0,20,length.out = 50),Inf),col.regions = tim.colors(n = 64))
```

The result looks like,

[image]

However, I still wonder if this can be achieved by using image.plot or filled.contour. levelplot seems troublesome when I try to add a basic plot to it.

Comment: I used `nn <- max(matrix)` and `levelplot(matrix, at = seq(0, nn, length.out = nn + 1), col.regions = colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "red"))(nn))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more complicated solution, which may allow for additional control of the scale axis:

```
library(sinkr) # https://github.com/marchtaylor/sinkr
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:15
z <- outer(x, y, "+")

ncolors <- 64
colors <- jetPal(ncolors)
zlim <- c(0,20)
breaks <- c(seq(zlim[1], zlim[2], length.out = ncolors), 1e6)


op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
layout(matrix(1:2,1,2), widths = c(4,1), heights = 4)
par(mar = c(4,4,1,1), cex = 1)
image(x, y, z, col = colors, breaks = breaks, zlim = zlim)
par(mar = c(4,0,1,4))
imageScale(z = z, ylim = zlim, zlim = zlim, col = colors, breaks = breaks, 
  axis.pos = 4)
par(op)
```

[image]

Here I show how you can specify the scale axis labels (e.g. the additions of a `>`):

```
# additional control
op <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)
layout(matrix(1:2,1,2), widths = c(4,1), heights = 4)
par(mar = c(4,4,1,1), cex = 1)
image(x, y, z, col = colors, breaks = breaks, zlim = zlim)
par(mar = c(4,0,1,4))
imageScale(z = z, ylim = zlim, zlim = zlim, col = colors, breaks = breaks, 
  axis.pos = 4, add.axis = FALSE)
axis(side = 4, at = seq(0,20,5), 
  labels = paste0(c(rep("", 4), ">"), seq(0,20,5)), las = 2)
mtext(text = "z", side = 4, line = 3)
par(op)
```

[image]